# Why does ld need /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 while its default dynamic linker is /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

In x86-64 target Debian, most of the programs are link against shared objects with the `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. And there is also one in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, so I delete it as I thought
it is unnecessary :

```
rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

then test :

```
gcc test.c
```

it showed as the following :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 inside /
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So , why does `ld` need to find the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` while the default dynamic linker is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` when linking ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/lib64/ is a symlink to /usr/lib64/.

```
cd /lib64/ && ls -l ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root .. ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so

cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ 
ls -l ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root .. ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.28.so
```

The main link to the linker **ld-2.28.so** is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` : Do not change it. (The link in /lib64/ and /usr/lib64/ is for compatibility reasons with certain software.)